# How enable mod_xsendfile?

Tags: apache

I installed mod_xsendfile on the apache server, How can I enable this module for the user correctly in Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS? I need to edit the apache main config file or user config file? Anyone, please help me with it?

here is the user apache configuration

```
<Directory "/home/users/rowan/www/">
  Require all granted
  Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

# domain.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAdmin test@gmail.com
  DocumentRoot "/home/users/rowan/www/"
  SuexecUserGroup "rowan" "rowan"

  # log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog "/home/users/rowan/logs/access.log" keyhelp_log
  ErrorLog "/home/users/rowan/logs/error.log"

  # php support
  <FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/keyhelp_rowan.socket|fcgi://keyhelp_rowan.socket"
  </FilesMatch>

  # Set some proxy properties (the string "unique-domain-name-string" should match
  # the one set in the FilesMatch directive.
  <Proxy fcgi://keyhelp_rowan.socket>
    ProxySet connectiontimeout=5 timeout=600000
  </Proxy>

  <Directory "/home/users/rowan/www/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes
    CGIPassAuth On
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Ubuntu has a [dedicated tool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/a2enmod.8.html).

Comment: This module configuration process is manual, I did configuration but not working.